# Mathematical writing, stopping time event

Tags: stopping-time

Given that I am not a mathematician, I'd like some help to write in the correct way this two events.

I know that $\begin{Bmatrix}
{\tau(\omega)\leq t}
\end{Bmatrix} \in \Im_t$ is the definition of stopping time, and I have this two examples:

1. the price of a share reached $20$ (this is a stopping time).
2. the price of a share reached its maximum (this is not a stopping time).

Knowing that the price of the share is $\Im_t$-adapted process $\begin{Bmatrix}
{S_t}
\end{Bmatrix}_{t \in [0,+\infty)}$, how can I "formalize" the examples above?

My attempts:

1. $A=\begin{Bmatrix}
   S_t=20
   \end{Bmatrix} \in \Im_t$;
2. $B=\begin{Bmatrix}
   S_t=\operatorname{max}\begin{Bmatrix}
   S_t
   \end{Bmatrix}_{t \in [0,+\infty)}
   \end{Bmatrix} \in \Im_t$.

But I suspect they are wrong. Could you help me?

Comment: For the first, are you looking for the first time S reached 20, something like this?$T_s=\min \{t>0 : S_t=20\}$. For the second, are you after the maximum value itself: $\max_{0\le s \le t} S_s$

Comment: @Magicisinthechain Thanks for your answer! Only one thing: the two events $\in \Im_t$, right?

Comment: The first one is a stopping time, the second is not because to know the maximum over interval T, we need to know the values of the process over the entire interval T. In contrast, for the first if we know values of S up to time t, then that’s enough to decide whether it has reached 20.

Comment: But running max of S itself is adapted like you said!

Comment: @Magicisinthechain Thanks again!

Comment: Just wanted to add that some format texts might use $T_s=\inf \{t>0 : S_t=20\}$ instead of $T_s=\min \{t>0 : S_t=20\}$. I think "inf" & "sup" are preferred over "min" and "max" for sets such as time which can go to infinity and are continuous. A good explanation about min, max, inf and sup can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/max-and-min-versus-sup-and-inf)